# When using cx_freeze, what files have to be updated to update the application?

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I want to implement an autoupdater in my Python application. This is no problem with the source version; Python doesn't care at all that the script it's running is trying to overwrite itself.

Windows, however, does care if an EXE tries to overwrite itself. My question is, does my EXE even have to overwrite itself? Or is the EXE just an interpreter, and I only have to overwrite library.zip?

If it does, is there any alternative to starting an updater application and shutting down the main EXE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cx_Freeze exe is compiled along with cx_Freeze, so in most cases you can safely leave it alone and just update library.zip. However, you should make sure that you prepare your updates using the same version of cx_Freeze that you froze the application with originally, in case it expects specific things about the files around it.

Also, the exe gets stamped with a version number relating to your application (you can see it in the file properties). If you don't replace it, that version number won't change.

If you do need to replace the exe, I believe the trick is to copy it to a temporary folder and re-run from there, so that it can replace the original. You can also look into update frameworks like [Esky](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky), which aim to handle these kinds of details for you. I haven't used that, so I don't know how well it works.

Comment: The standard way of doing things is to change the exe's name, actually.